# IFNULL eloquent

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

estoy trabajando un proyecto con laravel y tengo estas dos tablas, contenido y contenidos_imagen, debo hacer una consulta haciendo un join para que me traiga todos los campos de la tabla contenidos y el campo imagen de la tabla contenidos_imagen, la consulta me quedo de esta forma

```
$contenido = Contenido::join('imagen_contenido', 'imagen_contenido.contenido_id', '=', 'contenidos.id')
            ->select('contenidos.*',  'imagen_contenido.imagen' )
            ->where('contenidos.id', '=', $id)
            ->first();
```

el problema es cuando el contenido no tiene una imagen asociada, como puedo reemplazar por cualquier ya que si la consulta no se ejecuta el arreglo se devuelve nulo

Comment: Tal vez la consulta se puede proponer de otra forma, ¿tienes las relaciones creadas en los modelos?

Comment: si, en el modelo Contenido tengo belognsTo

Comment: Entonces Contenido pertenece a `imagen_cotenido` ?

Comment: perdon alreves, en el modelo de imagen defino el belognsTo que indica que una imagen pertenece a un contenido

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Construye la consulta de este modo:

```
$data = Contenido::with('imagenes')->findOrFail($id);
```

Posterior mandamos esta data recuperada a la vista y la iteramos del modo siguiente:

```
@if ($contenido->imagen===Null)
<input readonly type="text" class="form-control" name="img" id="img" value="No se ha cargado ninguna imagen">
@else
@php
$i=$contenido->imagen->imagen;
@endphp
<img src='{{asset("images/$i")}}' class="card-img-top" style="max-width: 20%">
@endif
```

Lo que hice fue:

- Los valores recuperados de contenido no se iteran pues solo estoy obteniendo un objeto producto del método `findOrFail`
- Como un solo contenido si puede tener múltiples imágenes asociadas entonces esto si lo debo iterar
- Estoy asumiendo que en tu modelo `Contenido` tienes la relación `hasMany` en un método llamado `imágenes` en caso que sea un nombre distinto solo cambialo en el código

**Referencias**

- [ciclo `forelse`](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/blade#loops)
- [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)

Comment: el lio es que en el formulario debe aparecer toda la info del contenido y en caso de no contener imagen retornar algun valor por defecto, para poder hacer un if y decirle al usuario que ese contenido no tiene imagen

Comment: ok @NicolasAldana dame un momento

Comment: vale, muchas gracias

Comment: @NicolasAldana revisa si la edición te es útil

Comment: gracias bro eres un crack, la persona que habia hecho este metodo se complico mucho, funciona a la perfeccion, gracias

Comment: me sirvió bastante tu ayuda pero tuve un problema al cargar la imagen a la etiqueta img ya que no me permitía acceder al atributo del arreglo imagen pero cambie la estructura asi y me funciono a la perfección, voy a modificar el codigo de tu respuesta, nuevamente muchas gracias